# How to access future value in initstate?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

How can I get the future value in initState of a state? I am trying to create a login screen that checks if session exist in the sqflite and returns accordingly. I have a DBhelper class that checks the database and returns session in Future. How can I compare this?

I also have a chat screen and I need to listen to websocket and send the username to the server on initstate. This username is also in the database and is returned as a Future value.

P.S I don't want to show loading on login page. I want to enter the home screen directly if the session exists in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code out of `initState()` to another method that you can make `async`, then call this method from `initState()`

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _someOtherAsyncMethod();
}

Future<void> _someOtherAsyncMethod() async {
  // do something async hree
}
```